# Must fix var folder permission after each cache clear , Symfony 4

Tags: permissions, symfony4, ubuntu-18.04

I'm using Symfony 4 and my website is hosted on ubuntu 18.04 server.

The problem is each time when I do clear cache I must run `chmod 777 -R var/`  .

Is there a command to fix permission permanently ?

Comment: I would assume you run the commands as a different user hence causing the problems. (meaning: the web server / php runs symfony under user www-data or something and you use root or something else) leaving the cache dir non-writable to the symfony user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely because the user for your web-server need to write in this directory. There are a few things you can do. First of all, you could clear the cache as your web-server user (quite like www-data, but this depends on your server software and whether or not you made any changes):

```
sudo -u www-data php bin/console cache:clear
```

A second option (and I prefer this) is to use 'access control lists' to give both you CLI-user and your web-server user access. First, install ACL by running `sudo apt-get install acl`. Then run the following ([source](https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/setup/file_permissions.html#using-acl-on-a-system-that-supports-setfacl-linux-bsd)):

```
 HTTPDUSER=$(ps axo user,comm | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1)
 sudo setfacl -dR -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:$(whoami):rwX var
 sudo setfacl -R -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:$(whoami):rwX var
```

After this you can clear the cache with your regular CLI-user.